# Delimiter in java

Tags: java, delimiter

I am trying to use a delimiter in Java, but it won't work(the standard white space delimiter is working).

My code is this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the first rational number seperated by '/':");
input.useDelimiter("/");
int numerator1 = input.nextInt();
int denominator1 = input.nextInt();


System.out.println(numerator1 + denominator1);
```

When I use the whitespace delimiter I get 12 as the output, but when I try to use "/", I get nothing.

Comment: What is your exact input?

Comment: I'm trying to input 8/4 to test the delimiter

Comment: [This IDEOne Example](http://ideone.com/LwNx7x) shows that your code works fine.

Comment: Program is perfectly fine ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` and `parseInt`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class delimiter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the first rational number seperated by '/':");
    String[] parts = input.nextLine().split("/");
    int numerator1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int denominator1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);


    System.out.println(numerator1 + " " + denominator1);
}
}
```

Input / Output :

```
Enter the first rational number seperated by '/':
8/4
8 4
```

*If you want to add the two numbers just use:*

```
 System.out.println(numerator1 + denominator1);
```

which outputs `12`

If you (or somebody else reading this) wanted to split with another symbol, you could use

```
       String[] parts = input.nextLine().split("\\+");
```

if you wanted to *split* `(8+4)` *in two parts* separated by `+` or

```
    String[] parts = input.nextLine().split("\\*");
```

if you wanted to *split* `(8+4)` *in two parts* separated by `*`

We need to use `\\` for `+` and `*` because these are `special` *which the regex needs to properly take care of*

*You can also use any other symbol you wish to split by* `(just change the argument of the split() function and be careful if it is a special character or not)`

Hope that helps

Comment: I believe OP is attempting to perform arithmetic addition; not concatenation. Despite your solution making perfect sense, OPs code should work perfectly.

Comment: @adrCoder , the program is running perfectly fine without any modification

Comment: Consider adding more informations about `split` method since person reading this code will probably also want to split on `+` or `*`.

Comment: I added some more information for `+` and `*` hope that helps :)

Comment: "to split with another symbol, you could use... `split("+")`" no, that is the trap your answer should prevent readers to enter. `split` is using regex and `+` and `*` are special in regex.

Comment: `Fixed it`. *Sorry* about that. Hope it is `ok` *now* :)

Answer (score 4):

The reason is because it's still waiting for more input.  The `nextInt()` method stops parsing when it encounters non-numeric input, discarding the rest of the token.  This line:

```
int numerator1 = input.nextInt();
```

reads the `8` and the `/` off the input stream, yielding the numerator of `8`,  but `4` is still in the stream.  The `Scanner` hasn't seen another `/`, so it doesn't know when the the next token will end.  It blocks.

If you enter another `/` then it will work.

```
Enter the first rational number seperated by '/':
8/4/
12
```